# Remove from PATH variable any paths that contains a space

Tags: bash, awk, sed, path

I am having issues cross-compiling in WSL. The problem is that some of the windows paths that are added to the PATH variable contain spaces that cause errors in some Makefiles.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_1.11.1.0_x64__76v4gfsz19hv4:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/tools/lxrunoffline:/mnt/d/pe_kit/Windows Performance Toolkit/:/mnt/d/pe_kit/Microsoft Application Virtualization/Sequencer/:/mnt/c/Users/IG-88/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
```

I need to remove any paths that contain a space. I know either sed or awk will probably do the job but I can't seem to do it myself. eg:

```
$ echo $PATH | some sed or awk command
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/tools/lxrunoffline:/mnt/c/Users/IG-88/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
```

Comment: Spaces themselves in the PATH are not necessarily a problem.  My PATH also contains several directories which contain spaces. Of course it makes sense to remove unneeded directories. The real question is: How did unwanted directories creep into your PATH in the first place? After all, you are controlling this variable, so I would put into it only stuff which is actually needed.

Comment: @user1934428 As I stated, I am using WSL. The path /mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_1.11.1.0_x64__76v4gfsz19hv4 for example is unavoidable. It's not in the windows path settings and nor is it in files like /etc/profile so I have no control. I don't want to mess up existing windows programs either. Like I said some Makefiles don't quote the PATH variable and cause build failures if there are spaces. Easiest way (for me anyway) is to remove problematic folders that aren't applicable to WSL by adding a line in /etc/profile hence the initial question.

Comment: When bash starts, several files are processed. Just put in one of those an initial statement of `export PATH=....`, where you explicitly set the path to the exact value you need and overwrite what you may inherit from Windows. This is much easier than fiddling around with its components afterwards. Further,if your existing toolchain is broken because they can't deal with spaces, I would fix those (programs, makefiles and so on) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo $PATH | sed 's|:/mnt/[a-z]/[a-z_]*\?/\?[A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]* \?[A-Za-z]*\?[^:]*||g'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/tools/lxrunoffline:/mnt/c/Users/IG-88/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
```

Comment: Just what I needed, a concise answer instead of the frequent baseless unhelpful comments that some posts seem to get. I added `export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed 's|:/mnt/[a-z]/[a-z_]*\?/\?[A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]* \?[A-Za-z]*\?[^:]*||g')` to `/etc/profile` and stuff like `make menuconfig` for openwrt works as expected (the sort of things you would think WSL was created for). Don't know why my question was downvoted for lacking details and clarity. I thought it could not be asked any simpler!

Comment: @5p0ng3b0b Glad to help. I believe it was downvoted/closed due to the fact that you asked a question without showing any of your efforts in finding a solution. Try and always include your efforts when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash then you can do

```sh
PATH=$(set -o noglob; IFS=':'; a=($PATH); IFS=' '; a=(${a[*]/* *}); IFS=':'; echo "${a[*]}")
```

Example:

```sh
myPATH="/win 1:/usr:/win 2:/usr/bin:/win 3:/usr/local/bin:/win 4"
(set -o noglob; IFS=':'; a=($myPATH); IFS=' '; a=(${a[*]/* *}); IFS=':'; echo "${a[*]}")
/usr:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

There's many approaches, I find this short and relatively readable:

```
PATH=$(grep -v '[[:space:]]'<<<"${PATH//:/$'\n'}"|paste -sd:) make
```

Edit: as per KamilCuk's suggestion.

For no Windows at all, replace the regex with `'^/mnt/c/'`. Simply `PATH=${PATH%%:/mnt/c/*} make` is also fine for this, in your case, and should be fine in the general case too I think. Unless you've *appended* something to PATH that you need in the build.

Comment: `|tr '\n' : ... ${tmp%:}` use `paste -sd:`